# How to select variables from different data.frames in shiny?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I'm exploring `shiny` and I'm trying to do some app that does the following:

- Let the user choose between two (or more) different data.frames (in my example I use mtcars and iris but I'm planning to use some self-made data.frames.
- Select some X and Y variables according to the data.frame selected
- Plot a simple x-y scatterplot

Code below:

```
df_list <- list(cars= mtcars, iris= iris)

ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Simple app"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("data", "Choose a database",
    choices=ls(df_list), selected=ls(df_list[1])),
    selectInput("xcol", "Variable X", names(data)),
    selectInput("ycol", "Variable Y", names(data))),

    mainPanel(

      plotOutput(outputId = "plot")

    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {
    selectedData <- reactive( {
        data[, c(data$xcol, data$ycol)]
    })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(selectedData())})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I feel I have two problems. The first one is pretty obvious since I can't make the app displays variables according to the data.frame selected. Second one is that I feel I'm missing something in my server function (I guess that's related with my first problem) so no plot is displayed.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few issues.  The following should work.

```
df_list <- list("mtcars", "iris")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple app"),
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput("data", "Choose a database",
                  choices=df_list, selected=df_list[[1]]),
      selectInput("xcol", "Variable X", c()),
      selectInput("ycol", "Variable Y", c())),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
      ,DTOutput("t1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mydata <- eventReactive(input$data, {
    get(input$data)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    req(mydata())
    choices <- names(mydata())
    updateSelectInput(session,"xcol",choices = choices, selected=choices[1])
    updateSelectInput(session,"ycol",choices = choices, selected=choices[2])
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT({mydata()})
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(mydata(),input$xcol,input$ycol)
    if (is.null(mydata()) | !(input$xcol %in% colnames(mydata())) | !(input$ycol %in% colnames(mydata())) ) {
      return(NULL)
    } else{
      selected_df <- mydata() %>% select(input$xcol, input$ycol)
      plot(selected_df)
    }
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow, that's more complex than I was thinking. I thought it could be solved with some minor adjustments. Definitely I need to read more documentation. Thanks!